# variable containing html table not stored in database in laravel 5.1

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, eloquent

getting content from `ckeditor` as `html` table  stored in a variable and send it to controller using ajax, after sending i am able get the content in the variable in controller but after inserting the variable into the database, the whole content is not stored.
But when i manually go to `phpmyAdmin` and ia can place the content there and save.
I tried---
1. php max_variable_allowed value change to higher value(1000 to 2500)
2. memory_limit value change (128 to 256)
but its not working

anyone can help me.. pls?

Comment: some code will be helpful

Comment: Which type of variable have you used ?

Comment: You should post your migration table with he field you are trying to store the code

Comment: the variable is a normal variable (php loosely coupled).

Comment: `public function foo_function(Request $request) {
 $id = $request->input('id');
 $foo_content = $request->input('foo_content'); //here i am geting exactly what is sent
 foo::create(['id'=>id,'foo_content'=>$foo_content]);
 }`

Comment: the content of the variable is a table having `table , td, tr, tbody` etc elements. the thing is the variable contains a cpmplete table but the create cannot store the complete table, as a result when mi display the varibale later on , it breaks the css of the page where it shown. i just want to store the complete thing whatever is in that variable $foo_content. Thanks